# Apache Poi Workbook - problem creating Workbook as a spring IOC managed bean

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, spring-bean

I have the certain problem:
I want to register Apache Poi Workbook as a bean but when I try to do that an exception is thrown stating that my file is zero bytes long
Here is the exact exception:  `Caused by: org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)` 
and this is how my actual code looks like :

```
@Bean
public FileInputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
       return new FileInputStream(EXCEL_FILE_PATH);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Bean
public Workbook workbook()  {
    try {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(getInputStream());
        getInputStream().close();
        return workbook;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

**This two methods are located in a configuration class annotated with the configuration annotation @Configuration** 
So how do I go about solving this issue provided that my file is not empty and the workbook instance works as it should when I tested in a separate test class which is not spring managed.

Comment: Why not return the `File` which can then be re-read as many times as you want? An `InputStream` can normally only be read once then it's empty

Comment: Remove the try/catch and you will see why. My guess you are trying to load a resource tha tis in the classpath and not an file from the file system. It also feels weird/wrong to have a `Workbook` defined as a bean.

Comment: Well,the problem was that I had the same file path in another outputstream.